# Limit of a cummulative sum

Tags: limits, summation

Is there a way to take the limit of the sum:
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{N^2} f(k_i)
$$
where $k_i=i/N$ and $f(k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow0$.

Comment: I think you need more structure on this. Is $|f(x)|<\infty,\;\; \forall x \in [1,0)$?

Comment: Also, do you want the actual value (very hard) or that it simply converges?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far as well -- o/w ppl will give downvotes.

Comment: For any function $f$ that is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ the limit is $0$, I don't think you can have more general answer with this little information. If the limit wasn't $0$ (in particular didn't exist), the function $f$ could not be integrable, which is quite interesting.

Comment: So I have an explicit form of $f$ it is just extremely messy. $f$ diverges as $x\rightarrow\infty$ but the way we generate $k$ should stop us having that situation occur. I've just been totally stuck due to the fact that $N$ appears in so many places. Unfortunately, I was hoping to find the actual value and not just prove convergence.